# Ambiguity error?

Tags: c#, ambiguity

So I'm rather a newbie when it comes to programming especially in c# i have an error i need help with?

So I'm trying to create a rpg system i started out before all else with the battle system which i just barely began my code which is store in Form1.cs is such

```
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public class Variables{

       public Graphics character;
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
        }


        }

        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.KeyCode)
            {
                case Keys.Up:
                    Player.Top = Player.Top - 5;
                    Battle.Steps = Battle.Steps + 10;
                    break;
                case Keys.Down:
                    Player.Top = Player.Top + 5;
                    Battle.Steps = Battle.Steps + 10;
                    break;
                case Keys.Left:
                    Player.Left = Player.Left - 5;
                    Battle.Steps = Battle.Steps + 10;
                    break;
                case Keys.Right:
                    Player.Left = Player.Left + 5;
                    Battle.Steps = Battle.Steps + 10;
                    break;
            }
            if (Battle.Steps == 100)
            {
                Battle.Fight = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and Battle.cs is

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{

   public class Battle
    {
      public static bool Fight {get; set;}
       public static int Steps; 
       public void Fight (){


    if (Fight == true)
    {

    }
       }
    }
}
```

However I'm getting an error Error      `Ambiguity between 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Battle.Fight' and 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Battle.Fight()'`
when i try to access the variable in form 1 and also when i try to edit in in Battle.cs
What's going on how do i fix this or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Show your `Battle` class.

Comment: Maybe try changing the name of  your `bool` property `Fight` to `Fighting`

Comment: RPG tag on this site refers to the venerable RPG programming language created originally by IBM, which is used primarily for business applications used at the core of businesses you encounter on a day to day basis.

Comment: You can't have methods and fields with the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Best I can figure without actually seeing your battle class is that you have a variable named Fight and a method Fight such as.

```
public class form
{
    {
        Battle battle = new Battle();
        battle.Fight = true;
        battle.Fight();

    }
}

public class Battle
{
    public bool Fight = false;
    public bool Fight()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

This would cause ambiguity as if you call fight it would have a hard time figuring out whether you are calling the variable or the method.  To Fix this maybe give your variable or your function a different name. Such as if the variable Fight is just a bool to see if they are in a Fight or should get into a fight maybe name the variable InFight or ShouldFight.

Comment: sorry for the mistake i put my battle class up :/

Comment: Same thing still applies you have a method and a property named the same change the Property public static bool Fight {get; set;} to Something like Fighting or IsFight.